# Why don't different URLs work at the same time?

Tags: php, url, cron, task

I have a php function that runs the code below.

```
    echo SystemService::getCurrentTime();
    
    sleep(10);
    
    echo '------------2----' . SystemService::getCurrentTime();

    die;
```

And this function is triggered via a url. The problem is that even if I open 4 same links from an incognito tab, they all have a delayed start time.

For example, I entered the links 4 times at the same time. The first started immediately, the second 20 seconds later, the third 30 seconds later, and the fourth 30 seconds later.

If the links are working lagging, then why does the second and third start with a delay and the last link starts at the same time as the third link?

Sample outputs are as follows.

```
1st link: 2022-08-17 16:27:07------------2----2022-08-17 16:27:17
2nd link: 2022-08-17 16:27:17------------2----2022-08-17 16:27:27
3rd link: 2022-08-17 16:27:27------------2----2022-08-17 16:27:37
4th link: 2022-08-17 16:27:28------------2----2022-08-17 16:27:38
```

They all have to start at the same time. How can I fix this?

Comment: You server supports only 1 worker (or task). But this is not an answer for the 4th  time.

Comment: Knowing which platform (or framework ) you are using to run php might help in explaining why it behaves this way.
On the surface, it appears their is only one process executing the codes regardless of how many tabs you are using, so long they are running simultaenously

Comment: I am using apache server and pure php. Why are links 3 and 4 running at the same time if it looks like a single process executing the codes?

Comment: I also have a situation like this. When I open more than one link from a normal browser and from an incognito tab in more than one link, it starts in both browsers at the same time. So when I open more than one link in the same browser, it works with a delay.

Comment: If you are using sessions, this is probably a case of [session locking](https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/).

Comment: No I don't use. session_status returns NONE when I print at the end of each link output. 
Even if there is such a deadlock, the last 2 links should not start at the same time.

Comment: _"When I open more than one link from a normal browser and from an incognito tab in more than one link, it starts in both browsers at the same time. So when I open more than one link in the same browser, it works with a delay."_ - so that would probably indicate that it is more of a client-side issue then. Have you used browser debug tools to check when the requests are _started_ by the browser?

Comment: I also checked the times with browser debugging tools. They also show the same delays. Also, I was solved the problem by running the same function with 4 different link structures (for example, xx.com/endopoint -- xx.com/endopoint_2 -- xx.com/endopoint_3 -- xx.com/endopoint_4). But I still don't understand why it lags with the same link structure.